# Installing headless ArcGIS Runtime SDK Qt Linux64 1026 on Linux Mint 19.1?

Tags: installation, linux-mint, arcgis-runtime-sdk-qt

I want to install ArcGIS runtime SDK on Linux with commandline.
I can't use wizard installer.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: I've always used PuTTY for an X11 SSH tunnel to XMing to install ArcGIS Server components. You should check with Esri Tech Support to see what your headless install options are. They will include the required X11 packages installed on the target host if it's the same InstallAnywhere binary tool.